# Only print p-values of a linear model in r

Tags: r, lm

Is there a way to only print the p-values of linear models in R? 
I only need the p-value of the global model, NOT of the coefficients.

[How to only print (adjusted) R-squared of regression model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564111/how-to-only-print-adjusted-r-squared-of-regression-model)
In this post is the solution for only printing the adj. r².

I tried `summary(model)$p.value`
but it is not working.

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587676/pull-out-p-values-and-r-squared-from-a-linear-regression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `broom` package:

```
library(broom)
# coefficient p values
tidy(model)$p.value

# model p value
glance(model)$p.value
```

Staying in base, you can use

```
# coefficient p values
summary(model)$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"]
```

In `base`, you can't get the model p-value directly out of the `summary` - it's calculated on the fly by the `print.summary.lm` method. You could replicate this calculation with

```
with(summary(model), 
  pf(
    fstatistic[1L], 
    fstatistic[2L],
    fstatistic[3L],
    lower.tail = FALSE
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This gives the p-values of each coefficient. 
I only need the p-value of the global model. Is there a way to do that as well?